# How to split spreadsheet into multiple files, and in each new file split data into multiple sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I would like to split my data with a VBA macro into multiple files, based on some criteria, and then in the new created files, split again according to another column filter (criteria).

Basically, there is two Youtube-Tutorials explaining each step alone, but I don't get it to mix them.

First one to split the main spreadsheet into files, and works for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCjqBlOk6f8

Second one to split a spreadsheet into multiple sheets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bOFNsdHiPk

The second doesn't actually have exactly my needs, as you have to do some manual steps, like selecting and naming the range that you need (i.e. "Master" and "SplitCode"). I have so many data and files to split, so I would like to have a macro splitting it automatically, without having manual steps in it like the 2nd tutorial. But it's actually almost what I need.

So trying to mix up both codes, here is what I tried, and it doesn't actually work:

```
Sub Split()

Dim wswb As String
Dim wssh As String

wswb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
wssh = ActiveSheet.Name

vColumn = InputBox("Please indicate which column you would like to split by", "Column selection")

Columns(vColumn).Copy
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "_Summary"
Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

vCounter = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To vCounter
    vFilter = Sheets("_Summary").Cells(i, 1)
    Sheets(wssh).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFilter field:=Columns(vColumn).Column, Criteria1:=vFilter
    Cells.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Master"


    dspColumn = "D"

    Columns(dspColumn).Copy
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "dspSummary"
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    dspCounter = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To dspCounter
        dspFilter = Sheets("dspSummary").Cells(j, 1)
        Sheets("Master").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFilter field:=Columns(dspColumn).Column, Criteria1:=dspFilter
        Cells.Copy
        Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = dspFilter
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Next j

    If vFilter <> "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Split Results\" & vFilter
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Split Results\_Empty"
    End If


    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Workbooks(wswb).Activate
Next i
'Sheets("_Summary").Delete

End Sub
```

Any help welcome!

Comment: Consider importing all data into a database (where they should have resided) and then export queries of data to specific Excel (the end-use application) workbooks/worksheets. Someone should tell the Youtube link folks: [Excel is not a database](https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+is+not+a+database).

Comment: Take a look at Power Query (add-in 2010/2013; built-in to 2016) -- I've done this and more without any VBA (nothing against VBA).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the code I posted above is working. The only problem was this line

```
ActiveSheet.Name = dspFilter
```

the copied dspFilter (sheet-name) was longer than the allowed 31 characters.

So changing that line to

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Left(dspFilter, 30)
```

solved the problem.

Thanks to anyone who commented, or tried to think about it.